# PHP websockets with nginx via SSL

Tags: php, nginx, websocket

How to setup websockets with PHP in nginx?

I have looked at this tutorial, but cant make it work

https://www.sanwebe.com/2013/05/chat-using-websocket-php-socket

Have copied the three files into the root of the www directory

`/index.php`
`/jquery-3.1.1.js`
`/websocket/server.php`

In `index.php` I have changed the URI

```
var wsUri = "wss://domain.com/websocket/server.php";
```

In nginx I have added this

```
http {
    map $http_upgrade $connection_upgrade {
        default upgrade;
        ''      close;
    }
    server {
        location /websocket/ {
            proxy_pass https://domain.com:9000/websocket/server.php;
            proxy_http_version 1.1;
            proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
            proxy_set_header Connection $connection_upgrade;
        }
    }
}
```

http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/websocket.html

To start websocket server

```
php -q /var/www/websocket/server.php
```

The chat is located at `https://domain.com/chat.php` and loads but get this error in the chat window `Error Occurred - Connection closed`

Have also tried to connect through this tool, but get this error

http://www.websocket.org/echo.html

```
ERROR: undefined
DISCONNECTED
```

If requested through browser

```
wss://domain.com/websocket/server.php


ERR_DISALLOWED_URL_SCHEME
```

Comment: I assume the error is displayed in the browser window, not nginx or php logs. Are you by any chance using google chrome to test this (https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/chrome/leVmLPNVISI )? If so, try with another browser.

Comment: Yes the error occurs in Google Chrome browser.. Have also tried with FF.. Here I don't even get an error

Comment: Try to eavesdrop on the traffic between your client and nginx and nginx and php, respectivley, using e.g. `tcpdump` to check if the setup is working as expected on the network level.

Comment: @TomRegner could you give me an exampe on how to do it?

Comment: Search here at SO for 'tcpdump websocket', the discussions you'll find should get you going

Comment: Have you figured out the solution? If so will you able to answer this question [Click Here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53411060/7713811)

Answer (score 4):

I have spotted few glitches in your config file; my observations are as follows:

- Running `php -q /var/www/websocket/server.php` will start simple socket server. It won't be SSL; i guess thay's why you are passing it through nginx. isn't it?
- Thus `proxy_pass https://domain.com:9000/websocket/server.php;` should not be https. You also don't need the full path as it's a simple tcp socket  and not a file path. Thus just `proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:9000;` should do.
- If you are implementing SSL at nginx; where are those settings?
- In all new browsers; you can't access unsecured http or ws resources from a secured https page.

Thus following is my config file which seems to be working as intended.

```
 server {
    listen 8080 default_server;
    listen 8443 ssl;

    ssl_certificate /home/ubuntu/Desktop/php-sock/newcert.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /home/ubuntu/Desktop/php-sock/newkey.pem;

    root /home/ubuntu/Desktop/php-sock;

    index index.php index.html index.htm;

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
        include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock;
    }

    location /websocket/ {
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:9000;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
        proxy_read_timeout 86400;
    }
}
```

Also make change in `index.php` to `var wsUri = "wss://localhost:8443/websocket/";`

Answer (score 2):

You're using port 9000 in your nginx configuration, while PHP's built-in web server runs on port 8000.

Try change the port to 8000 and see if that resolves it.

```
proxy_pass http://domain.com:8000/websocket/;
```

Edit:

Regarding ERR_DISALLOWED_URL_SCHEME

Chrome, since ~version 50, requires that all websocket communication be over SSL. You're probably going to need to enable that in order to have your app work in Chrome.

You have two options:

1. Use a certificate issued by a trusted certificate authority
2. Add the certificate manually to your trusted certificate roots. Your web application won't work for anyone who doesn't do this manually

Comment: Get the same error when requesting the websocket URL `ERR_DISALLOWED_URL_SCHEME`

Comment: Have now changed the config in nginx to run SSL, but still get the same error

Comment: Is the certificate you're using self-signed? Chrome could reject it for that reason as well

Comment: @clarkk I've amended my answer in response to your comment

Comment: I'm now on a trusted cert.. same issue

Comment: Try another browser to see if the issue is Chrome specific. If this solves it, the certificate probably isn't issued by a certificate authority recognised by Chrome

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/134081/discussion-between-karl-buys-and-clarkk).